# How do I change my image format?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to blur an image using PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter

im = Image.open("plot.png")
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
```

When I do `im.show()` and save it to my hard drive, it saves as a BMP file, which is incompatible with the place where I'm trying to upload it. How do I change the file format from BMP to something else that is compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [`save()` function](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) directly:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter

im = Image.open("plot.png")
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
im.save("saved.jpg")
```

This function supports many formats, as explained in the [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save).